# I'm having a problem I can't solve error with initGRASS code. This is the error I get:

Tags: spatial, grass

```
Error in system(paste("g.dirseps.exe -g", shQuote(Sys.getenv("GISRC"))),  : 
  'g.dirseps.exe' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
2: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
3: In initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.32.0/GRASS GIS 7.6",  :
  working directory not writable, using tempfile for GISRC
```

And my code is:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste0("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.32.0/bin",";", Sys.getenv("PATH")))
 
  initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.32.0/GRASS GIS 7.6", 
            home = tempdir(),
            gisDbase = "C:/GRASSDB",override=TRUE
           )
```

I am sure that the path is correct and QGIS download works. but I don't know what " 'g.dirseps.exe' not found"meaning and if this not solves, this error will appear again when I set up GRASS environment.